# Why When List sent to view it return correct length but all fields are empty?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

When List sent to view it return correct length but empty fields

I use foreach to iterate through the list to display each field in input element it iterate for example 5 times if the list length is 5 but all fields are empty

**View**

```
@model.myProject.TwoModels 
@using (Html.BeginForm("Edit", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @foreach (var tuple in Model.personList )
    {       
            @Html.EditorFor(model => @tuple.Name)                 
    }
```

**My model**

```
public partial class Person
{
        // set and get to id and name
        public Person(int Id,string Name)
        {
            Id = this.Id;
            Name = this.Name;
        }
}
```

**Classes**

```
public class A
{
   private List<Person> personList { get; set; }

   public List<Person> PersonList
   {
        get
        {
            return personList;
        }
        set
        {
            personList= value;
        }
    }
}

public class B
{
    public void method(B b)
    {
        b.PersonList = new List<Person>();

        //it's just example
        for (int i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
            b.PersonList.Add(new Person(1,"Ali")));
        }
    }
}
```

**I use this model to combines tow model**

```
namespace myproject.Models
{
    public class TwoModels
    {
        // example is another model
        public example firstModel { get; set; }
        public List<Person> personList { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public List<Person> method()
{
    A a =new A();
    B b =new B();

    //other code //
    return b.PersonList;
}

public ActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    List <Person> list = method();
    example ex=database.example.Find(id);

    var TwoModels = new TwoModels { firstModel = ex, personList = list };
}
```

Comment: It looks like you need to call `B.method(b)` in order to create the list and populate it.  Maybe instead of `method` in the `B` class that should be the logic of the constructor?

Comment: You might also want to read [Post an HTML Table to ADO.NET DataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30094047/post-an-html-table-to-ado-net-datatable/30094943#30094943) since nothing will work when you submit your form

Comment: @Stephen Muecke I know that It is just example not complete code, in view i have a submit button

Comment: It has nothing to do with not having a submit button - Read it - you cannot use a `foreach` loop to generate form controls!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `Person` constructor is backwards. Instead of this, which assigns the (null) values of each property to the local parameters:

```
public Person(int Id,string Name)
{
    Id = this.Id;
    Name = this.Name;
}
```

You need to assign the values of the parameters to the properties:

```
public Person(int Id,string Name)
{
    this.Id = Id;
    this.Name = Name;
}
```

To avoid this confusion in the future, you should also consider adapting the standard C# convention of using camel case for method parameters and Pascal case for properties. In this case:

```
public Person(int id, string name)
{
    this.Id = id;
    this.Name = name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a problem in your Person class constructor. You are wrongly setting the class members. This is the correct version:

```
public Person(int Id,string Name)
        {
            this.Id = Id;
            this.Name = Name;  
        }
```

Instead of your version which is actually setting the local function variables again:

```
public Person(int Id,string Name)
        {
            Id = this.Id;
            Name = this.Name;
        }
```